# How can I create complicated shortcuts in Geany?

Tags: shortcuts, geany

For [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B), we can use a macro to record and save a complicated function and assign a shortcut to it. How can I do a similar thing in Geany?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How do I record macros and assign a shortcut key in Geany?

Install the [geanymacro](https://plugins.geany.org/geanymacro.html) plugin:

> geanymacro is a plugin to provide user defined macros for Geany. It
>   started out as part of the ConText feature parity plugin, which was
>   split into individual plugins to better suit Geany's ethos of being as
>   light as possible while allowing users to select which features they
>   want to add to the core editor. The idea was taken from a Text Editor
>   for Windows called ConText.
>
> This plugin allows you to record and use your own macros. Macros are
>   sequences of actions that can then be repeated with a single key
>   combination. So if you had dozens of lines where you wanted to delete
>   the last 2 characters, you could simple start recording, press End,
>   Backspace, Backspace, down line and then stop recording. Then simply
>   trigger the macro and it would automatically edit the line and move to
>   the next. You could then just repeatedly trigger the macro to do as
>   many lines as you want.
>
> Select Record Macro from the Tools menu and you will be prompted with
>   a dialog box. You need to specify a key combination that isn't being
>   used, and a name for the macro to help you identify it. Then press
>   Record. What you do in the editor is then recorded until you select
>   Stop Recording Macro from the Tools menu. Simply pressing the
>   specified key combination will re-run the macro.
>
> To edit the macros you already have, select Edit Macro from the Tools
>   menu. You can select a macro and delete it, or re-record it. Selecting
>   the edit option allows you to view all the individual elements that
>   make up the macro. You can select a different command for each
>   element, move them, add new elements, delete elements, or if it's
>   replace/insert, you can edit the text that replaces the selected text,
>   or is inserted. You can also click on a macro's name and change it, or
>   the key combination and re-define that assuming that the new name or
>   key combination are not already in use.
>
> The only thing to bear in mind is that undo and redo actions are not
>   recorded, and won't be replayed when the macro is re-run.
>
> You can alter the default behaviour of this plugin by selecting Plugin
>   Manager under the Tools menu, selecting this plugin, and cliking
>   Preferences. You can change:
>
> - Save Macros when close Geany - If this is selected then Geany will save any
>     recorded macros and reload them for use the next time you open Geany, if not they will be lost when Geany is closed.  Ask before
>     replacing existing Macros - If this is selected then if you try
> - recording a macro over an existing one it will check before over-writing it, giving you the option of trying a different name or
>     key trigger combination, otherwise it will simply erase any existing
>     macros with the same name, or the same key trigger combination.

Source [Plugins for Geany](https://plugins.geany.org/geanymacro.html)

Comment: What was your experience using it? Many Geany plugins are buggy (e.g. *"Numbered Bookmarks"* intermittently stops working (that is, nothing happens when trying to use and set numbered bookmarks). It sometimes recover, but in most cases only a restart of the computer will fix it).

Comment: @PeterMortensen I don't use Geany ... :)

Comment: @PeterMortensen:  I just installed on Ubuntu via `sudo apt install geany-plugin-macro` and it works immediately in Geany.  I created a macro for Ctrl-B for bold text in HTML.  The recorded macro does not work straight away (due to interference with auto-replace of HTML tags), but the plugin lets you edit the macro's internal steps.  The macro editor is pretty good actually, except it has no help or instructions.  I think it's highly usable.